# function to save results in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm new to matlab and trying to write my own function to save results in matlab to a folder that i want. However, in the below code all the variables that i save seem to be saved with the same name i.e "resultName".I guess I'm supposed to do some input formatting to save my result name. How do i deal with this?
Thanks for your help

```
function [] = saveResults(variableName,resultName)
%save variable in  vName to resultName 
resultsDir = 'Z:\data\folder';
fNameCollections = fullfile(resultsDir,'resultName.mat');
save(fNameCollections,'variableName');
```

Comment: Read the documentation on `save`. It contains all the things you need.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this code is not working. From the [docs](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html)

> save(filename) saves all variables from the current workspace in a MATLAB® formatted binary file (MAT-file) called filename. If filename exists, save overwrites the file.
>
> save(filename,variables) saves only the variables or fields of a structure array specified by variables.

Since `save` is called inside a function, the variables is not defined in the current workspace. You may want to read up on the [basics](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf).

As earlier stated, it is all there in the function `save`. Just read the docs and you will be able to fix it. A good way to handle directories in Matlab is to keep information about directories in a struct, which is defined in some configuration file or a GUI. Then you can pass this struct on to the program. If you instead want a hardcoded path, then just hardcode when you call `save`. You probably want a date tag or something as well to avoid overwriting the files
.

Apart from this, a tip from a guy having made similar mistakes in his life. Having to write an extra few characters every time you save something is not worth all the effort you will get from debugging this. Sacrifice a few seconds of your valuable time and some skin on your fingers to avoid all the debug work which will follow your current approach.